# What is the difference in purpose and functionality between iframes and AJAX?

Tags: ajax, iframe, comparison

I have a site that I want to load links in the centre column, so why would I use AJAX over an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is a system which allows you to get data - any data - from a server. This is in contrast to iframes which simply load in a HTML document or fragment based on a given URL.

THe strength of AJAX's flexibility over iframes is their ability to give you back raw data *with which you then use to build or update your view*. Consider this example: you have a dataset that needs to be displayed in tabular form, so you could set up a page that contains the table with your data in it and load that in via iframe.

A better option however, is to get the raw data from the server with AJAX and send it to your application uncluttered by markup and extra tags. Your page then builds the table in whatever part of the page it needs, according to how your application needs it to appear right at that point.

Where iframes can load HTML content that must be presented as it is built, AJAX allows the developer to separate the data from the way it is presented, giving them the freedom to manipulate it as much as they like and use it in as many ways, pages and applications as they need.

### More Information

AJAX allows the client or web page to send data back to the server to do things with (such as changing passwords, updating settings, or transaction processing, etc.) so if your page or application needs two-way communication without refreshing the page, AJAX is probably the technology you'd use.

Also, using iframes restricts your ability to work with the data inside. An iframe creates a new *context* which you can think of as a container of sorts - the data inside is safe from the outside and vice versa. This often means your CSS won't flow down into your iframe giving you unexpected results. On some browsers, clicking a link in an iframe can actually cause the link's destination to load inside the iframe instead of changing the whole page - usually not what you want.

Comment: "AJAX is a system which allows you to get data - any data - from a server."

And you can also send data to server as well.